# CLLocationManager delegate / Multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a UITabBarController as my root controller, and in each tab I have a UIViewController.

I am using a singleton class for my location controller.

I would like to know the proper way to handle setting the delegate for the location controller.

When the app starts, the first tab is selected, and the UIVIewController on that tab loads the location controller, and sets itself as the delegate.

When I switch to the second tab, I also need the location controller, so I would like to know if I need to first set the delegate to nil in the first tab view controller's viewWillDisappear method, and then set it in the second tab view controller's viewWilAppear method,  OR, can I just set it in the second one without first setting it to nil in the first one.

*In short, must I nil the delegate before setting it again?*

I'm fairly certain that I can just set the delegate again, but I want to make sure this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to set to nil, just set new delegate in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.